# using presentviewcontroller inside a function swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, uiwindow, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to use this inside my function to present a view controller after a function runs, so included it inside

```
let window = UIWindow()
let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EmployeeTBCIdentifier")
rootViewController?.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It's not doing anything, it works if I use it inside viewDidLoad()

here's the main idea, and would it be possible to use completions according to this example,

```
func logInType(completion(Void1, Void2)->()) {
if login == employer{
    void1
}else if login == employee{
    void2
    }
}
```

when using the function I want to return this

```
func logInType{(void1, void2) -> void in
void1 = self.presentview //I want to push view to another if this code executed
void2 = self.presentview //same idea
}
```

updated : code is working but it's not pushing to the viewcontroller identified.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                        let window = UIWindow()
                        let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
                        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                        let setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EmployeeTBCIdentifier")
                        rootViewController?.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the whole function where you trying to present your viewController?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that there might be a problem in how you are getting the `rootViewController`. I think the `let window = UIWindow()` call is going to return a new `UIWindow` object instead of what you want which is the window that the root view controller (and your app) is associated with. Continuing this, `rootViewController` will be `nil` and your optional chain call `rootViewController?.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` won't do anything. Use an explicit unwrap via `rootViewController!.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` and you should see the error

To rectify, get the correct UIWindow another way, either from the `UIAppDelegate` or from another view controller using `OtherViewController.view!.window!`

Comment: I did what you said and it returned "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Yes, so you saw the error when you used `rootViewController!.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) `? That would be correct because rootViewController is nil. Use one of the methods I mentioned above to successfully grab the right UIWindow and retrieve the rootViewController from that.

Comment: I user "var window: UIWindow?" similar to appdelegates declaration.same error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and I explicitly unwrap the like what you said

Comment: The explicit unwrapping is just to show you that you are trying to use a `nil` value. The reason that `rootViewController` is `nil` is because you aren't getting the window properly. The declaration isn't the problem, it is that you are creating a new `UIWindow` which has no `rootViewController` when what you want to do is get the window you are using from your AppDelegate or another ViewController like `var window = AppDelegate.window` or `var window = SomeViewController.view.window`.

Comment: I understand, can u give an example of a code to get appdelegates window. AppDelegate.Window's returning "Instance member 'window' cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'"

Comment: What you are suggesting is that you have a complete lack of understanding of how to work with your app's window or your app's delegate, or even class vs. instance variables. Window is not a class property, it is an instance property. And the instance of your app delegate is what you need to use. `let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window` should work for you, but really you will run into many more programmer errors like this if you don't read more about these concepts.

Comment: hey scott,  I think it worked cause its now returning this "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!", could you educate me more about this, and it's true this problem is of lack of understanding. thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't. I can refer you to the documentation on ViewController programming though. I suggest you start there and when you encounter a concept you don't understand, dive deeper and read about that. If you encounter and specific questions, post them back here at SO and I'm sure you will get specific answers from me or other users. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH2-SW1

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like so:

```
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
              let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
              let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView") as! MainViewController
              self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Comment: I agree. I think you don't even need to use GCD. 
And in case of, prefer use guard-style/if_let-style instead of force-cast with as! (not critic but more secure)

Comment: i can't access self.presentviewController(vc,animated,completion), the property I can access is just  self.presentViewController(<#T##UIViewController#>)

Comment: @suisied could you try adding "as! yourViewControllerNamehere". My view controller name to which I want to move the view to is "MainViewController" you should try putting your destination view controller name.

Comment: I created a swift file and created a class inheriting UIViewController, now inside a class there is a function called login, I am trying to put this code inside the function, I know what you are suggesting, but I can't access properties, I already force unwrap it.

Comment: @suisied can you share your code with me so I can try it out and how it can be fixed.